# Need help with pulse sensor design modification

Tags: filter, signal-processing, low-pass, high-pass-filter

So I've got the below pulse sensor design. I don't understand why they filter before they amplify. I'd like to modify it in a way that I amplify the signal first, LPF second, HPF last. For some reason I am failing at it. Can someone suggest a design?

I have no idea why they are filtering first and amplifying afterwards. I would like to understand this too.

I have been told that its a good idea to amplify first as that would lead to better filter results.

What I have tried till now: I tried connecting the photodiode signal to R6, then pin 8 of Op amp on c1, and so on and so forth. The signal just dies.

I am trying to modify this circuit to measure pulses in animals, from rodents to primates.

[image: Schematic]
<sub>(Image source: Goyal P., Udeshi M., Tallur S. - IIT Bombay, India (no date) - [*Heart Rate Measurement using PPG*](http://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/%7Estallur/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Heart-Rate-Measurement-using-PPG1.pdf))</sub>

Comment: "I am failing at it": What does that mean? Please explain exactly what the problem is, else we don't have a question we can answer. Things that might help you describe what your problem is: 1. What have you done, and where are you stuck? 2. What is your reason to amplify first, filter after? What do you think the reason was the original circuit did it the other way around? 3. Describe what you need this for: what *actually* is the signal you're amplifying and filtering, and what you do with it afterwards? Please **edit** your question to include at least this level of detail!

Comment: I can't see anything that generates a pulse. Please explain how the pulse is generated and what rise and fall times it has and, what width.

Comment: @MarcusMüller edited

Comment: @Andyaka the human pulse is clearly visible, while I don't have a screenshot. My primary test is for human pulse. Pulse is generated by placing finger on the sensor

Comment: @DribbleNibble sorry, I don't understand. You can't attach a human pulse to a circuit. You need a sensor of sorts. So is that the photodiode you speak of? Where is the photodiode in your schematic? Why are you modifying the original circuit, if you don't understand it? Is it not performing well enough?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The IR emitter and receiver are on he left hand side of the circuit, you can see its labelled TCRT5000. Its working fine for humans, but I want to see if its performance improves on animals with amplification first and filter afterwards, as the pulse signal in especially small animals is high frequency and low amplitude.

Comment: Oh, OK; the symbol  used there is that of an optocoupler, so not the right symbol for the component! Your TCRT5000 is a reflective photosensor indeed based on a photo**transistor**, not a photo**diode**; that makes a lot of difference for the source impedance of the signal! Also, it means that the output is kind of already an amplified signal containing harmonics, and you **must** filter it before amplifying it any further.

Comment: @MarcusMüller really? didn't know that, I'm not exactly an electronics engineer. So no way to amplify it first?

Comment: your photosensor is already amplifying it. And: you're not actually solving any problem with more amplification if your photosensor doesn't give you a clean enough signal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller is HPF a "must" in this? For certain experiments I need an HPF of 0.05Hz, which I can make with a 10nF capacitor and a 20M Ohm resistor, but that might kill a low amplitude signal, from like a sick animal. Since the HPF value is already very low, could I just skip it? From an electronics point of view since you said filter before amplification is a must.

Comment: why would it "kill" a signal? It's a passive element; at worst, it *scales down* the signal. Yes, the noise figure gets worse if you put a lossy element up front; but the noise figure is dominated by the gain of the first stage in your signal chain, and that first stage is a transistor with significant gain: your signal simply isn't "weak" to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

A **DC analysis** of these three cascaded opamps shows that the last one connected through a series-connected diode to Arduino has a +ve quiescent DC voltage. Since this is an analog signal, the Arduino input pin should be an analog input - able to connect to an internal analog-to-digital converter. These ADC converters generally accept only positive voltages spanning zero volts up to a positive DC supply voltage.

The 330k input resistor **R3** causes a small positive DC offset, which undergoes amplification by **OPAMP_B** and by **OPAMP_C**. Since bias current of **OPAMP_A** that causes this DC offset varies from opamp-to-opamp, it is difficult to guess its magnitude. Fortunately, its sign is correct for the Arduino input:

- at OPAMP_A output, the offset is a positive voltage
- at OPAMP_B output, the offset is a larger-magnitude negative voltage.
- at OPAMP_C output, the offset is a still-larger magnitude positive voltage.

But offset magnitude may vary should another opamp be substituted, and will likely vary with temperature. 
. In addition to this, LM324 has no rail-to-rail output range - voltages between about +3.25V and the supply voltage of +5V cannot be reached. You might help this situation by adding a pull-up resistor to +5V at the final opamp output. This circuit is poorly engineered.

If you vary gain, or add a stage of gain, this DC offset should be arranged so that the final opamp has an average voltage of about half the +DC supply. Any gain change will affect this DC offset. Adding an inverting gain stage will cause this offset to go to a negative voltage - one that the arduino cannot accept.

Suggested signal processing arrangement:

- Each gain stage up to the final opamp should be AC-coupled
- Final stage should add a positive DC offset so that its output DC voltage is about half the Arduino's ADC range.
- Final stage should have low gain so that DC offset is predictable, and not subject to temperature effects.
- Use rail-to-rail opamps if you must use +/- 5V supplies.

[image: block diagram signal chain]

---

An additional problem likely exists, regarding the reflective optical sensor - its signal amplitude is affected by coupling distance to the animal (human). In addition, any ambient light leaking into this coupling cannot be discriminated from the desired signal.

Comment: What capacitor value would you recommend for this AC coupling?

Comment: Not enough information about the shape or time response of the pulse you're trying to amplify. Each coupling capacitor acts as a high-pass filter. The composite high-pass response of those amplifier stages should not distort the pulse...if you choose a capacitor value too-small, the pulse changes shape.